# How to fix a Resource not Found error in OC4J?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oc4j

I am trying to deploy a web app on OC4J, and although I've followed the instructions to the letter and the deployment process goes without a hitch, I keep getting a 500 error (below).  I am a newbie in OC4J, so I would appreciate some hints on what to look at and tinker with (XML/settings/etc) to fix this.  Here's the actual error, just in case:

```
500 Internal Server Error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource /login.do not found
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.EvermindPageContext.forward(EvermindPageContext.java:316)
    at _index._jspService(_index.java:46)
    [SRC:/index.jsp:14]
    at com.orionserver[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:453)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:591)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:515)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:711)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:368)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:866)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:448)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:216)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:117)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:110)
    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.1.0) ].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your index.jsp does a redirect to your login.do Struts Action; but your application isn't configured to re-direct .do urls to Struts. Is the Struts Action Servlet configured to be responsible for all *.do url mappings?  Please look in the web.xml configuration file (WEB-INF\web.xml) for an entry similar to this:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and a mapping to the servlet like this:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```